# How to copy data values in char** into a new char**?

Tags: c++, string, struct

**What I am working on:**
Hello. I currently have a `char**` variable, which is a pointer to an array of strings. I have a loop that occurs, and in this loop the `char**` needs to be backed up to a vector of structs. So the struct has a variable type of char** inside of it.
Unfortunately, for this piece I have to use the `char**` type. I am unable to use the `char* vName[]` type.

**What my problem is:**
The problem I am currently facing is that when I add a new struct, the `char**` points to the newest data available in ALL of the structs, not the most recent one.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried using `strcpy`, `memcpy`, and using the plain old values, but they don't seem to work. I have tried using `newItem.storedVars[i] = newVars` but that doesn't seem to work either.

How can I get or copy the data in the new `char**` array and store it into the struct without it being modified again by the loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct StringHolder{
    char** storedVars;                              //stored char** variable
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char** newVars;                                 //stores current char** values
    int counter = 100;                              //counter
    vector<StringHolder> vectorOfStructs;

    while(counter!=0){                              //while counter is going downward
        StringHolder newItem;                       //create a new string
        char** storedVarsToAdd;                     //stored variables that I will be adding

        newVars = externalVarsFetcher();            //get the new char** variable from the external function

        storedVarsToAdd = newVars;                  //this statement doesn't work

        //neither does this statement
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            storedVarsToAdd[i] = newVars[i];
        }
        newItem.storedVars = storedVarsToAdd;       //take the new item I created, update it's char** value with a new one
        vectorOfStructs.push_back(newItem);         //push the struct onto the vector
        counter--;                                  //continue through the array
    }
}
```

Comment: what does 'this statement doesnt work' mean? Do you mean it doesnt compile or that it doesnt do what you expect or your app crashes

Comment: You are just copying pointers around...think about what is the type of storedVarsToRead and storedVarsToRead[i]. You didn't even allocate memory for storedVarsToRead

Comment: @pm100 sorry, I meant that the first comment meant that it simply shows the newest data, not the copy that I want. The second one (above the loop) indicates that I receive a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are just juggling pointers, you are not copying the strings. You should be using `std::string`, but this sounds like homework so you have probably been told not to do that. If that's not the case use **`std::string`**

If you must use `char**` etc.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    storedVarsToAdd[i] = strdup(newVars[i]);
}
```

`strdup` will allocate memory and copy the string for you.

Now you have a potential memory leak but that's a different issue (hint - use `std::string`).

Comment: for sure, but 'teachers' of CS like to say 'dont use feature,x,y,z'. Note he says he is not allowed to use char*[]

Comment: You are correct in that it is "homework" in the sense that it is an online course. I do have to use char**, but I will try using strdup. Juggling pointers sounds exactly what I was doing.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to only copy junk and not the strings.

Comment: you also need to allocate memory for storedVarsToAdd

Comment: and as others havbe sais - this is not good c++, you are drowning in c++ anti-patterns

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to store the command-line arguments, which is the same thing you're trying to do:

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
   args.push_back(argv[i]);
```